# Move content for Box enterprise users

Tags: box-api

In previous iterations of the V2 API, and I think in the V1 API, it was possible for an Enterprise Admin to move content from one user to another, in an Enterprise Account. Is this possible with the V2 API? I can't seem to find a way to accomplish this.

Ideally, I'd like to reassign all content from one user to another when we find that user has left the company.

Comment: Apologies for the disappearance of the doc! Minor bug with the CMS behind our API documentation that's since been resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with the [Move Folder into Another User's Folder](http://developers.box.com/docs/#users-move-folder-into-another-folder) feature.

Comment: Yeah - the doco for that was missing until earlier today, after I informed someone from Box support and they got it back online. Thanks for the answer!